# How to change the foreign type for a polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a legacy database that I want to cleanup the model.
The database is shared between apps so I can't modify it.

I have a model named `Catalog` that relies in a `book_catalogs` table.
I do somethings like that to use the good table : `self.table_name = 'book_catalogs'`

The problem is when I want to define the `belongs_to :catalogable, polymorphic: true` in the model `CatalogBook`,
I can't find a way to override the `foreign_type` to `BookCatalog`.

Here is a subset of my model:

```
class Catalog
  self.table_name = 'book_catalogs'

  has_many :books, through: :catalogs_books
end 

class VirtualCatalog
  has_many :books, through: :catalogs_books
end 

class Book
  has_many :catalogs, through: :catalogs_books
end 

class CatalogsBook
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :catalogable, polymorphism: true, foreign_key: :catalog_id
end
```

And in my database, I have this:

```
catalogs_books
+------------+------------------+---------+
| catalog_id | catalogable_type | book_id |
+------------+------------------+---------+
| 15842      | BookCatalog      | 4567894 |
+------------+------------------+---------+
```

An ActiveRecord query example:

```
SELECT "books".*
FROM "books"
INNER JOIN "catalogs_books" ON "books"."id" = "catalogs_books"."book_id"
WHERE "catalogs_books"."catalog_id" = $1
AND "catalogs_books"."catalogable_type" = $2
[["catalog_id", 1], ["catalogable_type", "Catalog"]]`
```

How can I replace the `catalogable_type` `Catalog` by `BookCatalog` ?

Answer (score 1):

You use the `foreign_type` option:

```
class CatalogsBook
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :catalogable, polymorphism: true, foreign_type: :book_catalog, foreign_key: :catalog_id
end
```